# how can I split an arraylist to multiple strings?

Tags: android

I have to split an arraylist in to multiple strings in my app which should display in an order..

```
            ArrayList<String> contactlist = new ArrayList<String>();
            contactlist.add("Prasad");
            contactlist.add("Prasad");
            contactlist.add("Prasad");
            contactlist.add("Prasad");

            String[] contact = new String[contactlist.size()];
            contact = contactlist.toArray(contact);

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");

            for (String s : contactlist) {
                sb.append(s+",");
            }

            stringToSend = sb.toString();

            Log.d("stringToSend ", stringToSend);

            new upload().execute();

            /*
             * String[] rString = stringToSend.split("-");
             * 
             * for (String s : rString) { System.out.println("Names : " +
             * s); }
             */

        }
    });
}

class upload extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    String res, res1, url;
    ProgressDialog pd;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Sending",
                "Please Wait");
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            res = null;
            url = "http://192.168.0.40:8092/Testing/Login";

            //res = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpGet(url).trim();

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", stringToSend));

            res = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost(url, nameValuePairs);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        pd.dismiss();



        if (res != null) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "res", 1000).show();
        }

    }
```

I am getting response as prasad,prasad,prasad,prasad

I should get the response as

prasad

prasad

prasad

prasad

How do I do this?

Comment: Show your response spitting code.

Comment: I am not getting any idea on that..

Comment: I mean .. post the code how you response the list.

Comment: I am getting like this prasad, prasad, prasad, prasad..

Comment: I am not asking your OUTPUT , Can you post the full code ?

Comment: See you got a lot answers after you posted the full code. We can help you right only if you share the full code.

Answer (score 0):

**Need small loop**

```
ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();

        list.add("Prasad");
        list.add("Prasad");
        list.add("Prasad");
        list.add("Prasad");

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (String string : list) {
            sb.append(string+"\n");
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

**UPDATE**

```
for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
   list.get(i); // this is your individual string itself
}
```

Comment: its working but still it is an arraylist.. How to split into a string using split method?

Comment: you don't need to split and there is no such method to split. split() is method of String class not for ArrayList

Comment: Then how can I divide those strings from the arraylist?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
String str="";

for (Object object :  list){
              str= object + "\n";
             // System.out.println(str);
    }
```

Now in str you have a continious long String. To split this long string you can use the split method with "\n" as a delimeter as shown below:

```
String[] strList=str.split("\n");
```

Now in strList array you have required strings.

I hope the above code helps you.

Comment: its working but still it is an arraylist.. How to split into a string using split method?

Comment: Pls check updated answer. If helpful, then please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change your **`for`** loop. This will do.

```
  for (String s : contactlist) {
                sb.append(s+"\n");
            }
```

**EDIT:**

Convert your **`ArrayList`** to string array.

```
string[] myArray = (string[])list.ToArray(typeof(string));
```

Now your `myArray` variable has all the `prasad` values

You can access it like `myArray[0]`  , `myArray[1]` ... directly or using a for loop.

Comment: its working but still it is an arraylist.. How to split into a string?

Comment: Try the above method.